# How to detect mouseover events for a covered element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `<mark>` under a `<textarea>`. When I add `mouseover` listeners to the `<mark>`, the events do not trigger since they are under the `<textarea>`.

I cannot do `pointer-events: none` for the `<text-area>` since I want it to work as normal.

No jQuery please.

https://jsfiddle.net/aewc13nm/

Comment: Are the `<mark>`s under the `<textarea>` or within it? Please add your code so we can understand it better.

Comment: @KenoClayton Sorry, but can you please read the first sentence of my question... It literally states "I have some <mark> **under** a <textarea>." Anyways, I will add sample code now.

Comment: @KenoClayton nvm, I just realized the word "under" is ambiguous.

Comment: Not clear without some coding you tried please add your code so that we can understand what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are trying to find a solution that is independent of css and layering of the elements/siblings. In that case I can think of a way to rebuild a custom mouseover/out. It works by listening global mousemove on window and check with ~17ms whether we are crossing the boundaries of the mark element (I combined with custom event incase you have more complex nested elements within, its not necessary):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/k2sztvw8/)**

I added math random, so that you can identify different mouseover/outs.

```
!function(){
  var mark = document.getElementsByTagName("mark")[0],
        mouseout = true,
      mouseover = false,
      customMouseEvent = new CustomEvent(
        "customMouseEvent",
        {
            bubbles:false,
          detail:{
            mouseout:function(){return mouseout},
            mouseover:function(){return mouseover}
          }
        }
        );
      mark._lastGesture = "mouseout";
    window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    if(mark._busy){return}
    mark._busy = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      var rect = mark._rect || (mark._rect = mark.getBoundingClientRect());
      if(
        (e.clientX - rect.left < rect.width)
        && (e.clientX - rect.left > 0)
        && (e.clientY - rect.top <= rect.height)
        && (e.clientY - rect.top > 0)
      ){
        mouseout = false;
        mouseover = true;
      } else {
        mouseout = true;
        mouseover = false;
      }
      mark.dispatchEvent(customMouseEvent);
      mark._busy = false;
      setTimeout(function(){delete mark._rect},17);
    });
  });
  mark.addEventListener("customMouseEvent",function(e){
    if(e.detail.mouseover() && this._lastGesture !== "mouseover") {
        this._lastGesture = "mouseover";
        document.getElementById("feedback").textContent = "Mousover! " + Math.random();
    } else if (e.detail.mouseout() && this._lastGesture !== "mouseout") {
        this._lastGesture = "mouseout";
      document.getElementById("feedback").textContent = "Mousout! " + Math.random();
    }
  })
}();
```

Comment: I actually solved this using a similar technique by myself. There is only one major difference between our solutions. I used `.getClientRects()` instead of `.getBoundingClientRect()`. When the text wrapped, the later will not work since there is more than one bounding boxes and `.getBoundingClientRect()` only gets a rect that contains all. However, `.getClientRects()` will return all small rects.

Comment: Amazing, I'm glad we are on the same page about this. Don't forget to throttle the event handler and save the rects because getBoundingClientRect/Rects trigger browser repaint/reflow which can be expensive if repeatedly called within a short interval. good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `contenteditable="true"` instead of `<textarea>` 
Like this

```js
function up(x) {
    x.style.fontSize = "24px";
}

function down(x) {
    x.style.fontSize = "16px";
}
```

```css
.textarea-parent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.editable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-parent">
  <div contenteditable="true">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
    consecte, sed do <strong>tur adipiscing elit</strong> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
    <br>there is a  at the end?
    <br>tur adipiscing elit.
    <br>
    <br><mark onmouseover="up(this)" onmouseout="down(this)">Great</mark>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I still want to use textarea. I will accept if there is no other way around.

Comment: I think you cannot add html code in textarea just multi-line plain-text

Comment: I added another answer with the code that you included

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `z-index: 1` on `span` tag like this

```js
function up(x) {
    x.style.fontSize = "24px";
  }

  function down(x) {
      x.style.fontSize = "16px";
  }
```

```css
textarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
textarea, span {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 5px;
}
span {
  z-index: 1:
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id='t'></textarea>
    <span>Hello <mark onmouseover="up(this)" onmouseout="down(this)">world</mark>!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now the `<textarea>` isn't working because the span is covering over it, which is the point of this question.